# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. Firebase Authentication error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add firebase authentication in my project but it is giving me an error repeatedly. I have tried all the possible solutions that is available on YouTube but it not worked. Now its being very hectic to me, i have already worked on firebase authentication but this time the firebase update is different. Error is :-

/FirebaseAuth(17093): Creating user with demo123 with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  (17093): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(17093): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - The email address is badly formatted.